# Unable to load IDLE (Python GUI)

Tags: python, python-idle

I have installed Python 2.7 (Windwos 7). However, I am unable to load the GUI. I get no response when I try to open. I re-installed it but again the same problem.  What might be the solution?

Comment: What happens when you do try to open it?

Comment: Yes, I am not been able to open it. Nothing happens. Neither it opens or complains any errors.

Comment: please try `import _tkinter`: Does this work?

Comment: please, guys, welcome the new SO user. If you downvote him, explain him why. Lets help people to learn python in this great community

Comment: I wonder if I should downvote all "I recommend this IDE" answers... not usefull at all... The challenge is to get IDLE working...

Comment: I know the challenge is to solve the IDLE problem, but if I am in a desperate situation then I personally wouldn't care if someone gave me a quick alternative solution, even if it doesn't directly solve whatever was impeding me.  So in that sense I would not say such an answer is "not useful at all". I agree that it doesn't solve the problem, but it could have been that this question went unnoticed or unsolved and poor Docker would not have been able to continue on his Python journey because nobody even gave him an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be lot of reasons and its difficult to diagnosis and recommend a solution without looking into the actual system and process. If you are really interested to resolve this I can suggest how you can debug these issues.

1. [Download Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)
2. Bring up process Monitor and filter all process except pythonw. PythonW is the process that runs when you start IDLE.
3. Now Start Monitoring in Process Monitor.
4. Bring up IDLE and wait until Process Monitor's Log becomes stable.
5. Now study the LOG to see what might have gone wrong.
6. If you need more help, just post the log here and we can try to see what is wrong with your system.

Just to simulate your problem, I renamed my idle.pyw so idle_1.pyw and tried to bring up IDLE. It failed without any message. I then brought up process Monitor, and filtered the pythonw process and tried to bring up IDLE again. I found a message in the log which was in coherence with the problem.

[image]

As you can see, I have highlighted the error which shows what the error yes. Try the process explorer and this would surely nail down the problem if nothing works for you :-)
Remember, just search for **ThreadExit** in the log, the Error should be just above the Operation. In case its difficult for your to figure out the problem, just post the screan shot near the **ThreadExit**, and we can help you out.

---

Update from the Image Provided
[image]

As you can see in the log, the FSECURE.DLL closed the thread abruptly. FSECURE (Antivirus/Firewall) didn't think this process to have legitimate rights to do some operation. If you need to know more details as to what operation was blocked you would get from Fsecure Log. In most cases as you have experienced, running as an Administrator would help the process gain the right to not being blocked by Fsecure.

I have no expericne with Fsecure, but most antivirus have a Whitelist entry where if you add a process would prevent it from blocking it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed instructions. I downloaded the program and was also checking another answer, that fortunately help me identify the problem. And yes, I am able to make it work with administrator rights.

Comment: @Docker, Keep this tool handy. If any time, any windows process misbehaves and you have no clue what the problem is, this would work as elixir.

Comment: Sorry, that seem to be spam stuff. I tried to upload the image along with my question, but it seems that I need to have at least 10 points to upload image. Shall i email it (If you provide me with your email address)?

Comment: Are you using Fsecure antivirus/firewall? It is possibly abruptly closing the thread. It most cases Fsecure didn't recognize the process as a legitimate process to do certain operation. As you did, in most cases running it as an administrator / installing it would actually bypass such issues. If you see the process name next to ThreadExit operation, its FSECURE.DLL. FSECURE.DLL is part of the FSECURE Internet suite. That gives you a hint as to why IDLE ended abruptly. You will get more information from FSECURE Log.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. And Yes, I do have Fsecure installed.

Answer (score 4):

If you have python in the default installation path, try in the windows shell:

```
C:\Python27\pythonw C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```

or change the path accordingly. This should work even if you have other conflicting pythons in your installation or paths are not set.

1. If idle comes, best solution is to modify idle.bat (in idlelib
   folder) with the above explicit paths and create a desktop direct access to that new .bat.
2. If idle doesn't come, try

   - starting idle as administrator
   - starting idle after shutting down windows firewall

Comment: Thanks a lot. Starting idle as administrator worked. But I would be more than happy to make it work for another account. Sorry that I couldn't even vote for these beautiful answers. I really appreciate all answers.

Comment: Did you installed python for all users? [Check this](http://blog.dinel.org.uk/?p=125)

Comment: Yes. Is it so that I had to make only for the current user?

Comment: No, Check the link I gave to you. If you installed for all user it should be OK. You have some problem of permissions to execute idle or maybe to write on the configuration file .idlerc that should be in  your user  directory... Something is wrong in this respect as idle works when you call it as administrator.

Comment: Very good. it works with my Python 3.4 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing python 3.3.2 on my Windows 7 Professional x64.

During the setup I had to provide administrator privileges due to turned on UAC. Ever after when trying to start the IDLE nothing would happen - unless I started it as an administrator.

I checked the setup but couldn't make out an option for a non-admin install as described in http://bit.ly/15WBouF.

Inspired by the comment of Joaquin from above I deleted the entire folder named .idlerc located at my user directory. Et voila - IDLE runs as a charm!

Althought the root of the problem is still unknown to me this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, IDLE would stay silent and crash after couple more tries.

Then I tried to run the code from command line: >>python program.py
the command line said that I had problem with global variables. You have to declare a variable global in the beginning ot everyfunction before reaching it:

```
var1
def func(): 
   global var1
   ...code..
##end of func()
```

IDLE would not show that problem. It's a handy tool, but sometimes leaves you speechless.

Answer (score -1):

In keeping with simplicity, may I suggest removing Python 2.7, and download the stable version without known IDLE issues. That'd be Python 3.3.3. Click here --> [**Python 3.3.3**](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/) Python 3.4.1. is *problematic*.

1. Please select 'Start' > 'Computer' > Right Click on 'Computer' > Select 'Properties'.
2. Select 'Environmental Variables'.
3. Select 'New' or 'Edit' Variables. Path of the python.exe. **C:\Python33**.
4. Either Edit or input new Variables with naming conventions. This should remedy any issues with IDLE. However, regarding the GUI - may I suggest the following: **5)** In the Command Prompt, type: **cd C:\Python33**. This should take care of it. Hope this helps.